# OBJECTPROPERTY DOES NOT EXIST

Tags: mysql, sql, object-property

I have a database called test containing a table called Categories. I want to find the primary key column name in this table.

I wrote this SQL query:

```
Select COLUMN_NAME
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
Where OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA+'.'+CONSTRAINT_NAME), 
'IsPrimaryKey') = 1 AND TABLE_NAME = 'Categories'
```

SQL Error:

```
Error: ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION test.OBJECTPROPERTY does not exist
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your SQL query runs just fine for me on SQL Server 2012, in the Northwind database for the table 'Orders' instead of 'Categories'. What SQL DBMS are you using?

Comment: Most probably you have refered it as `test.OBJECTPROPERTY` and removed that from posted code.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens:SQL Version: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.23, for Linux (i686) using readline 5.1

Comment: @Rahul: I verified it. I have specified OBJECTPROPERTY only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's why you are getting the error. `OBJECTPROPERTY` is a `SQL Server` built-in function and not present in `MySQL`. Moreover, your posted query will never compile cause that's a SQL Server specific query.